# Passing objects of different derived class as a parameter to a function that expects base object of class

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, base-class

I have a base class **Device** and inherited class **InputDevice**. In class XYZ I have a function ***XYZ::setDevice(int num, Device device)*** that expects object Device as parameter. When I call the function setDevice() with parameter that is sublclass of Device (InputDevice) it gets converted to Device and I can't access the derived functions of derived class afterwards.
So if I want to call the function of "device" in function setDevice() it calls function of Device instead of overriden function in class InputDevice.
What am I doing wrong?

```cpp
void XYZ::setDevice(int num, Device device) {

    printf("%s\n", typeid(device).name());                    //this prints "Device"
    this->devices[num] = device;
}

XYZ::XYZ() {
    printf("%s\n", typeid(InputDevice(cin)).name());          //this prints "InputDevice"

    setDevice(STANDARD_INPUT_DEVICE, InputDevice(cin));
    printf("%s\n", typeid(devices[0]).name());
}
```

Comment: Change `void XYZ::setDevice(int num, Device device) {` to take the parameter as reference: `void XYZ::setDevice(int num, Device& device) {`

Comment: This is called *object slicing*. The fundamental problem is not `setDevice` it's `this->devices[num] = device;` which is also going to have the same object slicing problem. You need to store pointers to your devices (preferably smart pointer, like `std::unique_ptr<Device>`).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I don't see the full code, but instead of storing objects, you should store pointers. Your devices array should be vector or array of Device pointers.

Here's a fully working example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Device {
public:
    virtual string getName() const {
        return string("Device");
    }
};

class InputDevice : public Device {
public:
    string getName() const override{
        return string("InputDevice");
    }
};

class XYZ {
    Device* devices[10];

public:

    void setDevice(int num, Device *device)
    {
        devices[num] = device;
        cout << "Name : " << device->getName();
    }

};

int main()
{
    Device* dev1 = new Device();
    Device* dev2 = new Device();
    InputDevice* dev3 = new InputDevice();
    XYZ xyz;
    xyz.setDevice(0, dev1);
    xyz.setDevice(1, dev2);
    xyz.setDevice(2, dev3);
}
```

Comment: That way i won't be able to pass in object of class OutputDevice

Comment: The code is now legal, but clearly does not solve the OPs problem since they are going to have the same problem of an `InputDevice` being converted to a `Device` when you assign the object to the `devices` array.

Comment: I don't see the full code, but instead of storing objects, you should store pointers. Your devices array should be vector or array of Device  pointers.

Comment: @brmRush That comment should be your answer, instead of the code above.

Comment: Thanks for comments, you're right I should've done that first. Fixed it.

Comment: Hope it fits right now. Sorry I'm new here, just trying to help.

Comment: It works now after you edited answer, thanks. So if I understand correctly the problem was object slising, right?